# Connecting current sense output to ADC

Tags: current-measurement, low-pass

Just another case where my lack of knowledge of analog circuits comes out.

I would like to connect current mirror output of [DRV8245](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/drv8245-q1) to [ADS114S08](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads114s08) ADC.
The driver datasheet suggests adding "a capacitor in the range of 10 nF to 100 nF on the IPROPI pin to ensure OCP detection". So, that would be the left part of the circuit below.

I don't need momentary current data, only an average at about 10~20 samples per second. So, the right part of the circuit is a low-pass filter before ADC. Technically, the current mirror removes the need in an amplifier or a buffer. However wouldn't the capacitor in RC affect the capacitance on IPROPI pin as seen by internal OCP circuit?

In short, is the schematic below OK, or should I, for example, get rid of C1 and somehow adjust RC filter so it can perform the same function?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLRer1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The effect of c2 will be reduced since most of the current will sink through R1. I didn't study that long datasheet carefully but I think you can leave both in.

Comment: @user1850479 That was my first thought. The second one was that at 25kHz strange things may begin to happen.

Comment: @user1850479 I've asked this question on TI forum and got pretty much the [same answer](https://e2e.ti.com/support/motor-drivers-group/motor-drivers/f/motor-drivers-forum/1172542/drv8873-interfacing-with-mcu). So, if you convert your comment into an answer I'll accept it.